# export action in custom admin is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, export

Here is my code.

**Grid.php**

```
   protected function _prepareColumns()
        {

            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('repair')->__('CSV'));
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('repair')->__('XML'));


            $this->addColumn('id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('repair')->__('ID'),
                'align'     =>'right',
                'width'     => '50px',
                'index'     => 'id',
            ));

             $this->addColumn('product_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('repair')->__('product_id'),
                'align'     =>'right',
                'width'     => '50px',
                'index'     => 'product_id',
            ));

            $this->addColumn('detail', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('repair')->__('detail'),
                'align'     =>'left',
                'index'     => 'detail',
            ));
}
```

**Controller code**

```
public function exportCsvAction()
    {
        //echo "exportCsvAction"; die;
        $fileName   = 'repair.csv';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('repair/adminhtml_repair_grid')
            ->getCsv();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }

    public function exportXmlAction()
    {

        //echo "exportXmlAction"; die;
        $fileName   = 'repair.xml';
        $content    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('repair/adminhtml_repair_grid')
            ->getXml();

        $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);
    }
```

Comment: what's an error you are getting?

Comment: no error.... but when i click on export button... it is going to .. http://192.168.1.140/magemay/index.php/repair/adminhtml_index/exportCsv/key/a6f319dfc250f2dffb701db3baf10a7b/

Comment: now itz done.. actually i am using wrong method  _sendUploadResponse() ...... Right method to export data is _prepareDownloadResponse($fileName,$content); which contain 2 argument filename & content.

Comment: how about adding return parent::_prepareColumns(); in your  _prepareColumns() functions?

Comment: it is done now.. thanks for your valuable comment.. :)